# How to destructure component props if they aren't always present

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a Form component that gets both 'values' and 'errors' as props from its parent.
I am using remix run, so I don't need to keep the props as state. I also don't always need to pass down errors as one of the props.

```
const Form = ({values,errors}) => {
...
}
```

Is there a way to use the spread operator to only destructure props being passed down, or should i simply be passing an empty value for errors anyway?
Thanks!

Comment: If this is a React component, you will always be given a props object, so your code will run fine. Unless you're not talking about destructuring props but destructuring errors; in which case you need to provide some more code so we know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a default value:

```
const Form = ({values,errors} = {}) => {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses (they helped me get to the answer), I had thought that if I tried to destructure the props and they hadn't been set by the parent it would cause errors, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Parent:

```
<Form cat="Tom" />
```

Form component:

```
const Form = ({cat,dog,hamster,rabbit}) => {
  if (dog !== undefined) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to have errors as an empty array by default ( since there maybe be more than one ) in case there are no errors.
But there are also libraries that implement it as undefined when nothing went wrong, it really depends on the situation.
In the case of form validations see:
https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#errors--field-string-string-
to understand how some libraries approach that.